# How to change Docker ENV var?

Tags: shell, docker, environment-variables

While building a `Dockerfile`, I often allow to configure arguments during build time to make configuring only slightly different containers easier to build. To achieve this, I use defaults for the `ENV` vars combined with user definable `ARG`s. Example `Dockerfile` to quickly test with:

```
FROM busybox
ARG FLAGS
ENV FLAGS ${FLAGS:-}
RUN echo "${FLAGS}"
```

This then can be used like this:

```
docker build --build-arg FLAGS="foo --remove-me" -t <imagename>:<tag> .
```

Now I find myself in the situation that I do want to actively remove a specific flag (in above example: `--remove-me`) from a command that I allow to run (due to a bug not fixed since more than a year). While I know how to remove the flag in other situations:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/ --remove-me//'
```

I am facing the problem that I have no idea how to pipe and remove the flag. I know that I can do it while using `RUN`, but then I would have to repeat above `sed` usage for every `RUN` statement, therefore not making it repeatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading about shell variable replacement in [this *AskUbuntu* answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/595292), I gave it a try:

```
ENV FLAGS ${FLAGS//--fully-static/}
```

However, I ran into the following error:

> ```
> Missing ':' in substitution: "${FLAGS:-}" | "${FLAGS//--fully-static/}"
> ```

First I found out that Docker only supports a limited bit of bash [variable replacement methods](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/docs/reference/builder.md#environment-replacement). Finally I could find the `shell_parser.go` file in the [Docker GitHub Repo](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/f8656a6e37ded7d1558b4003c7a527861cd3aef6/builder/dockerfile/shell_parser.go#L221-L274) where it's clear that the `:` must be there, which actively kills any efforts going down this route right in the first step.

Answer (score 0):

Run in the same issue. My workaround is:

Use login shell to read .profile:

```
# need docker >= 1.12
SHELL ["bash", "--login", "-c"]
```

Create new environment variable with substitution:

```
RUN echo "export PROXY_HOST_IP=${PROXY_HOST#"http://"}" >> ${HOME}/.profile
```